# NLTK frequency distribution for group of words

Tags: nltk, frequency-distribution

Could you please help me how to calculate frequency distribution of "group of words"?

In other words, I have a text file. Here is a snapshot:

[image: a snapshot of it is given here]

Here is my code to find the 50 most common words in the text file:

```
f=open('myfile.txt','rU')
text=f.read()
text1=text.split()
keywords=nltk.Text(text1)
fdist1=FreqDist(keywords)
fdist1.most_common(50)
```

In the results, as you can see in the link, each word is calculated. Here is a screenshot of the results:

[image: a screenshot of the results]

It works well, but I am trying to find the frequency distribution of each line in the text file. For instance, in the first line, there is a term 'conceptual change'. The program calculates 'conceptual' and 'change' as different keywords. However, I need to find the frequency distribution of the term 'conceptual change'.

Comment: Welcome to stack-overflow.  You can improve your question a little by providing some information about what you tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: Also: What does the input file actually look like? Show a few lines.

Comment: I have edited my question according to your suggestions

Answer (score 1):

You're splitting up the text by *any* whitespace. See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split), this is default behavior when you do not give any separator.

If you were to print out the value of `text1` in your example program, you would see this. It's simply a list of words -- not lines -- so the damage has already been done by the time it's passed to `FreqDist`.

To fix it, just replace with `text.split("\n")`:

```
import nltk
from nltk import FreqDist
f=open('myfile.txt','rU')
text=f.read()
text1=text.split("\n")
keywords=nltk.Text(text1)
print(type(keywords))
fdist1=FreqDist(keywords)
print(fdist1.most_common(50))
```

This gives an output like:

```
[('conceptual change', 1), ('coherence', 1), ('cost-benefit tradeoffs', 1), ('interactive behavior', 1), ('naive physics', 1), ('rationality', 1), ('suboptimal performance', 1)]
```

Comment: hey I have a somewhat similar question and I was wondering if you could help me out. I am not splitting the words as the OP per se, I am using an NLTK Text as input and I get the words 'heart' and 'rate' separately. Is there a way around this?Thanks in advance! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45531514/nltk-freqdist-counting-two-words-as-one