# NLTK FreqDist counting two words as one

Tags: python, nltk

I am having some trouble with NLTK's FreqDist. Let me give you some context first:

- I have built a web crawler that crawls webpages of companies selling wearable products (smartwatches etc.).
- I am then doing some linguistic analysis and for that analysis I am also using some NLTK functions - in this case `FreqDist`.
- `nltk.FreqDist` works fine in general - it does the job and does it well; I don't get any errors etc.

My only problem is that the word "heart rate" comes up often and because I am generating a list of the most frequently used words, I get `heart` and `rate` separately to the tune of a few hundred occurrences each.

Now of course `rate` and `heart` can both occur without being used as "heart rate" but **how do I count the occurrences of "heart rate" instead of just the 2 words separately** and I do mean in an *accurate* way. I don't want to subtract one from the other in my current Counters or anything like that.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What sort of tokenization are you doing before you call `FreqDist`? Is it possible to pre-process "heart rate" into something like "heart_rate" as a hack (or do you want to avoid that)?

Comment: @whrrgarbl first of all thanks for your reply! I am doing `nltk.word_tokenize` and then using `nltk.Text` for the `FreqDist`. I would be open to smth like that at this point. Do you mean going through the text first and joing `heart` and `rate` with a `_`, and if so at which point in the pipeline?

Comment: Right, you could do it before or after tokenization. Preprocessing is sometimes frowned upon by NLP purists which is why I asked first :) I can write up an answer if this helps.

Comment: @whrrgarbl it would be awesome! while I do get the gist of it, seeing an implementation or at least a description thereof would help a lot :) And I do get the preprocessing "sentiment"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to accomplish this is by pre-processing your text before you pass it to `FreqDist`. This could be done before or after you call `word_tokenize` (assuming that's the only other step in your pipeline, otherwise it depends on what the other steps are doing).

You also have to decide if you want to distinguish between occurrences of "heart rate" and "heartrate", or treat them both as the same "word". If you want to distinguish them (and again, if it won't mess up later steps), you could call it something like `heart_rate`. This keeps it as one "word", but distinct from "heartrate".

I'll use this as an example sentence:

```
original = "A heart rate monitor measures your heartrate."
```

To do this before tokenization, you could do a simple `replace`:

```
def preprocess(text):
    return text.replace("heart rate", "heart_rate")

txt = preprocess(original)
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(txt)
nltk.FreqDist(tokens).tabulate()
```

This results in:

```
monitor       your          .   measures  heartrate heart_rate          A
      1          1          1          1          1          1          1
```

If you wanted to treat them the same, you'd just change it to `text.replace("heart rate", "heartrate")`. This would result in:

```
heartrate   monitor      your         .  measures         A
        2         1         1         1         1         1
```

If you want to process after tokenization, it is a little more complicated since you now have a list of tokens to loop through. Here's an example:

```
def process_tokens(tokens):
    deleted = 0
    for i in range(len(tokens)):
        i = i - deleted
        if tokens[i] == "heart":
            if tokens[i+1] == "rate":
                tokens[i] = "heart_rate"
                del tokens[i+1]
                deleted += 1 # keep track so we don't get an IndexError later
    return tokens
```

When this finds a "heart" token, it checks if the next one is "rate", and if so merges the two. Again, you can change it from `heart_rate` to `heartrate` if you wish. This function would be used like:

```
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(original)
nltk.FreqDist(process_tokens(tokens)).tabulate()
```

Giving the same results as the first.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you :) Now it seems obvious but well hindsight is always 20/20. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem, glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a well-known problem in NLP and it is often referred to Tokenization. I can think about two possible solutions:

- try different NLTK tokenizers (e.g. twitter tokenizer), which maybe will be able to cover all of your cases
- run a Name Entity Recognition (NER) on your sentences. This allows you to recognise entity present in the text. This could work because it can recognise Heart rate as a single entity, thus as a single token.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution! And I do know what Tokenization is :) I am asking _specifically_ if there is a way to build an 'exception' (not exactly the right word but I think you get the point) into NLTK's `FreqDist`? I might come back to using other tokenizers but it's _just_ this one case that I want to account for at the moment

Comment: I see. I think NLTK is open source.... but too much effort for just for so little modification. You could still use a NER to create a single token for that kind of couple words ('Heart rate'), and then simply use numpy to do the FreqDist.  Ps: sorry, I define tokenization just for completeness :) Hope this other comment helped

Comment: Thanks for the reply and yeah NLTK is OSS; I might have to go the NER route. In any case I need to solve this in the next few days.. I'll get back to this post with my final solution (I'll probably try what you suggested)